# Cannot output a value which is expected for class function

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I expect to have error when parameters aren't being passed, but instead I have just environment property.

```
const settings = require("../../settings.json")

class Space{
    constructor(length, width, height){
        this.width = width
        this.height = height
        this.length = length
        this.environment = settings.environment
    }

    create(){

        if(this.length == undefined || this.width == undefined || this.height == undefined){
            return { error : "Missing element!" }
        } else {
       settings.environment[0].space = this.height * this.width * this.length
       settings.environment[1].objects = true
       return settings
     }
    }
}

module.exports = Space
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the parameters that would throw an error if they are undefined.

Comment: how can I do it

Comment: how are you using this class?  if you create a new Space object it runs the constructor which doesn't care what parameters are passed to it.  If _after_ you create that Space object and call `.create()` it will return your error object.  create() doesn't run "on creation" of the class if that's what you're thinking.